# Adding search to an existing Rails index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this index method in my rails app

```
  def index
    @articles = if params[:user_id]
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      user.articles.page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    else
      @articles = current_user.articles.page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    end
  end
```

which allows me to limit posts by a user with a route like "/users/1/articles"... all good...

But I also want to add simple single filter on the article content so I can limit articles with a path like this:

/users/1/articles/foo
and
/articles/foo

where foo is search on the article content field. There are tons of tutorials on adding search, but I can't figure out how to make them work with an existing method. Plus, I don't need a search form or a separate search path.

Comment: Your `else` shouldn't contain `@articles =`. The whole point of putting `@articles = if...` is that, which ever branch executes, the result will be assigned to `@articles`. You've basically written your else to do `@articles = @articles = current_user....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains references to the "current_user" method. Are you using Devise or something for authentication? If that's the case, you should have a before_filter for :authenticate! at the top of your controller. Once you have the code there, you can just use "current_user" inside of your action (i.e. index method).

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate!

  def index
    if params[:search_term]
      @articles = current_user.articles.where('content like ?', "%#{params[:search_term]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    else
      @articles = current_user.articles.page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    end
  end
```

Also, if you want to pass in search terms as part of the URI, you need to add a route to your routes.rb

```
get "users/contents/:search_term" => "users#index", as: :users_contents
```

Comment: I would add that this will only do a simple search to see if the full search terms parameter is contained within the article content. "foo" will match "fool", "up down" will not match "up and down", etc. This is pretty much the bare minimum search functionality, and there are better, more robust, and higher performing methods out there. This may or may not be good enough, depending on the situation.

Comment: You are right, @np. You can use things like Lucene/Solr. There is a gem called "sunspot" that allows you to easily use a Solr implementation.